# TUN Module Loaded but OpenVPN /dev/net/tun no such file or directory

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, openvpn

lsmod -> tun 16587 0 - Live 0xbf0e1000

Openvpn error: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun no such file or directory

I tried creating a dummy directory but the error changes to Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Is a directory.

edit:
System: ARM Linux 3.10.0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/dev/net/tun is `character device` not file nor directory. Check it with `ls` command:

```
ls -lad /dev/net/tun
```

It shall look like (notice first `c`):

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 200 Feb 10 21:38 /dev/net/tun
```

To fix unload `tun` module:

```
rmmod tun
```

remove /dev/net/tun directory if it exist (directory is marked with `d` instead of `c`):

```
rmdir /dev/net/tun
```

Reload `tun` module:

```
modprobe tun
```

It shall create `character device` /dev/net/tun.

Comment: I unloaded tun and deleted the /dev/net/tun directory that I created. modprobe tun doesn't work and outputs 'module tun.ko not found'. Instead I loaded the module using insmod. The character device is NOT being created

Comment: @Luke what kind of system is that? (please add the info in your question, not in comments)

Comment: Check system logs (for example `dmesg | tail`) immediately after loading tun module. Probably it will show some error.

Comment: dmesg does not show an error

Comment: try to create tun device manually `mknod -m 0666 /dev/net/tun c 10 200`

Comment: I created the tun device and tunctl says "can't open 'dev/net/tun': No such device", which is slightly different than in the picture I posted.

Comment: I would guess that your tun.ko module is unoperable. Normally `modprobe tun` shall work while `insmod tun.ko` shall fail because it needs complete path to tun.ko (something like `insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/tun.ko`). Please tell which Linux distribution do you use and how did you get that tun.ko

Comment: Thanks for the support. The linux distribution is: linux-3.10-at91. I downloaded the source and compiled the module. I had been trying to get the module working with the existing linux-3.10-at91 kernel but in the end what I had to do was re-install the kernel. I'm sure that the problem resides in the config and several required options to utilize tun in the initial kernel were left out.

Comment: Kernel modules are tightly coupled with kernel itself. If you change kernel config than you must rebuild and install both kernel and modules and finally reboot to activate modified kernel. Use `make modules_install` command to copy built modules into proper directory. It will fix `modprobe tun`.

Comment: Check if kernel config has DEVTMPFS enabled. If I am not wrong it is responsible for automatic creation of `/dev/net/tun`.

Comment: I see. I loaded the original kernel and DEVTMPFS was not included. Enabling it corrects my issue, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Puppy Linux Xenial x64:

https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/ipfire/openvpn/

Note: If the VPN cannot start for you and you are getting this output:

> ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)

Then do the following:

```
mkdir -p /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
chmod 600 /dev/net/tun
cat /dev/net/tun
```

---

If you receive the message:

> cat: /dev/net/tun: File descriptor in bad state

That means your TUN/TAP device is ready for use.